# Tooth brushing Vs. Tooth cleaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

I saw in the book "essential grammar in use" (Cambridge publishing)  the following sentence:

> I **cleaned** my teeth three times a week.

Is it talking about brushing teeth?  I'm not sure about that because I've never saw **cleanining** teeth as a synonym of **brushing** teeth. Also wikipedia shows the article "tooth brushing" without noticing that there's a common synonym as usual wikipedia does.  Is tooth **cleaning** and tooth **brushing** are the same or cleaning is about other means that cleans the teeth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clean one's teeth = BrE usage

brush one's teeth=AmE or NA usage

reference: I just know this based on knowing speakers with both types of English.

[Personal knowledge is valid linguistic knowledge. There is no need for dictionary if one knows the answer. If someone feels the need to do so, they can enter their own answer. That's fine.]

Comment: BrE uses both "clean" and "brush" one's teeth. But always a "toothbrush"

Comment: @Lambie Dentists use *cleaning* all the time. *I'll book you for another cleaning.* I've never heard them say *brushing*, aside from when they specifically refer to the activity itself. However, I agree that when you talk about the activity *yourself* it seems to be North American to say *brushing*.

Comment: To have one's teeth cleaning, or to get a cleaning is another thing.

Comment: It's always better to have a reference from a vetted source than a single person's alleged knowledge. I don't understand why you edited it out; it made your answer sound more credible.